# Why does the tenant with the sick wife say "If I believed that, I would never have opened the door."?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-raid

In the Raid (2011), after the tenant with the sick wife agrees to shelter Rama and Bowo in his apartment, he tells Rama that Lieutenant Wahyu is corrupt, to which Rama responds, "Not every cop is swayed by money, sir." The tenant then replies, "If I believed that, I would never have opened the door."

Why would he never have opened the door if he had believed that not every cop is swayed by money, i.e. if he had believed that not every cop is corrupt? I thought that the main reason he allowed Rama and Bowo into his apartment was because he thought Rama was a good person for helping him bring the medication in to his wife when the other people on the SWAT team didn't want to let him enter the building.

Comment: If he believed that every cop was corrupt, by definition he would never be **able** to believe that Rama was honest.

Comment: @Catija Oh!!! I misunderstood what the word "that" was referring to when it was spoken by the tenant. I assumed it was referring to Rama's statement "not every cop is swayed by money," but it was only the latter part of the statement, without the word "not."

Comment: It's probably mostly an error in the dubbing/subbing but that's what they *mean*. It could be a construction in the original language that's fine but doesn't quite work in English... or they could have just fumbled it slightly.